# Retrieving elements with a made-up CSS attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I fetch the value of a non-standard CSS property via Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249991/can-i-fetch-the-value-of-a-non-standard-css-property-via-javascript)

How can I use jquery to retrieve all elements with a made-up or non-standard CSS attribute? For example, if the attribute is "emotion" and its value "happy", how could I traverse the dom and retrieve the element with said attribute, and if necessary, it's value?

HTML...

```
<div class="book">
</div>
```

CSS..

```
.book {
emotion:happy;
}
```

Javascript/jquery query to find book by it having the emotion attribute.

```
???
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you're going with HTML5, you can use `data` attributes: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml

Comment: Why would you not want to just use a class?

Comment: I would use `class="book emotion-happy"`,then it can be accessed/changed using `.className`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround someone mentioned to me in person is to use a CSS parser, such as: http://glazman.org/JSCSSP/index.html

Comment: Hey good link! `:)` +1 to you anyways!

Answer (score 4):

Invalid or unknown CSS Properties(*not attributes*) will be ignored by the browser, and there is no way to access them as they are not added to the DOM.

Comment: Yes; that, and why would one want to create a non-standard CSS attribute?

Comment: +1 and for duplicate mention as well `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use data attributes as in here:

```
<div class="book" data-emotion="happy"></div>
```

and get with jQuery as:

```
$('.book[data-emotion="happy"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get elements with arbitrary attributes in the DOM:

```
​<div emotion="happy">:)</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
...
console.log(​$('div[emotion="happy"]').text()​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​);​
// prints ":)"
```

... but it's better to do:

```
​<div data-emotion="happy">:)</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
...
console.log(​$('div[data-emotion="happy"]').text()​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​);​
// prints ":)"
```

Because using [`data-` user-defined attributes is recommended in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

It won't be parsed as a CSS rule, either, and why would you want that?

Comment: I am trying to write something in JavaScript that supports future CSS

Comment: You shouldn't be selecting by properties OF a CSS class, anyway. Select by the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

Although I reckon you can / should not be searching elements based on css property:

Rest I hope it helps the cause `:)`

plz try this:

```
var x = $('div').filter(function(){ return this.style.some_prop == 'whatever' });
                                                        ^------- ------ ^
```

**Note: In case you want to search with respect to the attributes see here**

```
$(parentElement).find('*[someAttributeName]').each(function(index){
    doSomething(this);
});
```

Comment: @zallarak brilliant and you downvoted because? what is not working? can you explain a bit? please `:)`

Comment: @Raminson lol Thanks bruv, lol I will up vote you as well wait, `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit yes, it does not work nor did the other guys' example which you both asserted worked until I posted a jsfiddle [now deleted]. Not trying to argue with you guys, I am just trying to figure it out.