# Do custom CSS properties use one leading dash or two?

Tags: html, css, styles, css-selectors, css-parsing

```
#elem {
  -myCustom: 99;
}
```

OR

```
#elem {
  --myCustom: 99;
}
```

I have seen both of the above used in examples online. What the difference between the two?

Trying to access custom properties in JavaScript returns null..

```
#elem {
-myCustom: 99;
}

<div id="elem">some text</div>

elem = document.getElementById("elem");
style= window.getComputedStyle(elem);
value = style.getPropertyValue('-myCustom');
alert(value);
```

Comment: I'm quiet sure that `-myCustom: 99;` is invalid and it would be ignored by (most of) web browsers. (I'm also sure that it is not related to any kind of browser hacks).

Comment: @HashemQolami Technically the browser should ignore it because it's a custom property, but even a custom property should still be accessible through getComputedStyle().

Comment: Actually it is an *invalid* property (custom property, has a special meaning now). However I'm not sure if [non-standard CSS properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249991/can-i-fetch-the-value-of-a-non-standard-css-property-via-javascript) could be accessible by JavaScript.

Answer (score 10):

- single leading dash is used for vendor prefixes
- double leading dash is used for defining [custom properties](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/).

> **[2 Defining Custom Properties: the '--*' family of properties](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/)**
>
> A custom property is any property whose name starts with two dashes
>   (U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS), like `--foo`. The `<custom-property-name>`
>   production corresponds to this: it’s defined as any valid identifier
>   that starts with two dashes.

An example from W3C:

```css
:root {
  --main-color: #06c;
  --accent-color: #006;
}
/* The rest of the CSS file */
#foo h1 {
  color: var(--main-color);
}
```

It's worth noting that CSS variables are implemented in Firefox 31 and newer.

Comment: Note: CSS Variables only work in Firefox 31+ — they've been pulled from Chrome https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/ScKw9zYRkBc. Not working in Safari and IE also :)

Comment: What a difference 6 and a half years makes... CSS Variables are now supported by all major browsers including Chrome, Edge and Safari (not supported on IE or Opera Mini): https://caniuse.com/css-variables

Answer (score 0):

Custom properties use one dash, by convention followed by the renderer/software.

For example:

-webkit-box-shadow

-moz-box-shadow
...

But it seems that there is a new feature implementing two dashes, this might be interesting for you:

http://www.broken-links.com/2014/08/28/css-variables-updating-custom-properties-javascript/

Comment: Hey I was just reading that same article but can't get the JavaScript to return any value except for null. WTF?

Comment: I have not yet read the article completely, maybee you could post a snippet?

Comment: Have you implemented an element in your HTML with that id?

Comment: We have learned that custom properties start with two slashes. So what about changing it to --myCustom? Otherwise... I will have a look at it tomorrow and try it out

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. However it still returns null, very strange considering there's so many examples online that say it works. Also tried FF31 and Ch. Still null. Thanks for your help! I do look forward to your further comments on this.

Comment: Works fine in Firefox 32:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   body {
    --test: 5px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   alert(window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--test'));
  </script>
 </body>
</html>`

Comment: These are not custom properties; these are vendor extensions which are an entirely different concept from custom properties.