# Grabbing CSS Value and Placing it as an HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm trying to do grab the tabIndex from this line:

```
<input name="110" title="" id="test" style="position: absolute; top: 155px; left: 687px; tabindex: 3; z-order: 99;" type="checkbox" CHECKED="checked" runat="server" value="on"/>
```

And have it set as an HTML attribute via javascript.

How can I achieve this?

Ideally what I'm looking to see is this:

```
 <input name="110" title="" id="test" tabindex= "3" style="position: absolute; top: 155px; left: 687px; ; z-order: 99;" type="checkbox" CHECKED="checked" runat="server" value="on"/>
```

Comment: you cant use jquery ??

Comment: only if its jQuery 1.0. Its to run on IE 8

Comment: With access to jquery, you can use `$("SELECTOR").attr("tabindex") = "desired index"`

Comment: You have some errors in your inline CSS: `tabindex = 3` and `z-order`

Comment: The above was taking from a page with a tonne of check boxes in it. But I'll look into the z-order thing.

Comment: @Callum. I'm not trying to reset the tab index, I'm hoping to move, or at least copy, the tab index into the HTML attribute

Comment: `tabindex = 3` is invalid in css.did you mean `tabindex : 3` ??

Comment: @Sean So you want that tab index applied to the direct HTML element?

Comment: @Sean might want to check this link out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249991/can-i-fetch-the-value-of-a-non-standard-css-property-via-javascript.  It shows how to fetch non-standard css properties in both IE and other browsers.  Then you can use the setAttribute function from there.

Comment: @Callum. Yes as opposed to it sitting in the CSS Style, I would like it to be set as an attribute. I'll update my question

Comment: I believe I misunderstood you initially, as the code `$("SELECTOR").attr("tabindex") = "desired index"` will set it as an attribute, and not within the CSS. Why are you doing this in Javascript and not simply placing the tabindex in the elements directly?

Comment: According to W3Schools "In HTML5, the tabindex attribute can be used on any HTML element", so simply setting it like you have in your suggested edit above, will be valid markup.

Comment: This code is generated via a form designer that was created back in 2000. The person I'm editing this for will not update so I'm stuck with what I've got. For one thing, they use IE 8 and not anything newer.

Answer (score 0):

`tabIndex is not a style property it should be out side style attribute.`

To get `tabIndex`

```
var x = document.getElementById("test").tabIndex;
```

To Set `tabIndex`

```
document.getElementById("link3").tabIndex = 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

While I have no idea why you would have a tabindex set in the style, which isn't legal syntax, you can get it through a regex.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myInput");
var match = elem.getAttribute("style").match(/tabsize\s*:\s*(\d+)/);
if(match) {
    elem.setAttribute("tabindex", match[1]);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0syvw3Lo/1/
Note that this only works if that was set inline, not with a CSS sheet.

Comment: The above code is generated in a really convoluted way and this is the issue I'm trying to fix. I'd thought moving the css out of the style part and into a new attribute would easy.

Comment: @Sean Well what we're saying is that tabindex isn't CSS at all. It's an error to have it in the style attribute in the first place. That's why it's hard to retrieve it.