# Is it possible to locally extend web API to allow CSSRule.cssText to return a non standard css attribute

Tags: javascript, css, mozilla

I am experimenting with passing a value to javascript from within a style sheet.
I have seen that I can get the values for a selection using CSSRule.cssText:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule/cssText
but if I want to use a property value pair that is not recognized as css it doesnt show up.

The issue of whether you can return a non-standard value was addressed here:
[Can I fetch the value of a non-standard CSS property via Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249991/can-i-fetch-the-value-of-a-non-standard-css-property-via-javascript)

I am curious if there might be some workaround where I could locally add my property to the list of accepted css attributes so that it would be returned by CSSRule.cssText?

Comment: Interesting use case, why do you need this? If a property is not supported the browser isn't going to be able to do anything with it either way.

Comment: @Halcyon: Not the browser, but it may still be of use to the developer.

Comment: The developer could also just look in the CSS source file right? Browsers these days have pretty good tools for showing you which CSS rules are applied and where they're define (file/line). If this is a legitimate use case I fail to see it's purpose.

Comment: @Halcyon: Yes but accessing those values through developer tools is not the same as accessing them programmatically.

Comment: That's like saying driving your car in reverse is not the same as driving your car forward. I get that, but if you're going to drive your car backwards, why not take the bus instead?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `content` property of a pseudo `:before` or `:after` element to pass a string which then can be parsed to an object. May not be an elegant way to do this, but seems to work.

```js
var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0],
    h1 = document.getElementById('foo'),
    customProp;

/*
ParseData function was taken from :
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1496-ask-ben-parsing-string-data-using-javascript-s-string-replace-method.htm
*/
function ParseData( strData ){
  var objCollection = {}
  strData.replace(
    new RegExp( "\\[(\\w+)=([^\\]]*)\\]", "gi" ),
    function( $0, $1, $2 ){
      objCollection[ $1 ] = $2;
    }
  );
  return( objCollection );
}
// you could as well target the content property directly here.
customProp = ParseData(stylesheet.cssRules[1].style.cssText);
h1.innerHTML += customProp.foo;
```

```css
#foo {
  color: tomato;
}

#foo:before {
  content: '[foo= loves Bar!]';
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="foo">Foo</h1>
```

Comment: I am going with content as an interim solution. So far no one has tried to answer what i asked however. Just speculate on why I would want to do this and give me a another way to acheive something silimilar. My question remains however, can I get javascript to give me:
.className{
    myMadeUpAttribute: valueIWant;
}

Comment: obviously it doesnt give me anything usable as css, I just wanted to see if I can put some values I want to access there. thanks.

Comment: Possibly no, but you can store data in the DOM (data attributes and other custom attributes). Invalid CSS will not be parsed and can not be accessed and is pretty useless. Why not use a CSS class and give it the values you need or set HTML attributes in the DOM where it was meant to do?