# How to get a style attribute ime-mode from a CSS class by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have input with cssclass imeoff like

```
.imeoff{ime-mode: disabled}
```

I want to read the property ime-mode by using

```
style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    top = style.getPropertyValue('ime-mode');
```

but the code above just run on IE and Firefox, not work on chrome.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

"ime-mode" is a property somewhat implemented in some browsers, that is problematic and officially obsoleted by this specification.

Chrome will not support ime-mode
[image]

There is a new DOM API `CSS.supports` to check CSS property validity. FF, Opera (as supportsCSS) and Chrome Canary already implement this method.

Try `CSS.supports("ime-mode", "disabled")`, This will return false.

Comment: ya, i see, so i want to read the property to display an alert

Comment: JS cannot read a property which is not there in DOM. If your code return empty string on chrome, you have to assume that the property is not valid.

Comment: ok, thanks. So do you have any suggestions to get the invalid property?

Comment: use CSS.supports API to check the validity of CSS property, I am updating the answer with the code

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, I don't think Chrome recognizes `ime-mode` as a valid css property, check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r92460xt/1/)

```
function getTheStyle(styleName){
    var elem = document.getElementById("elem-container");
    var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue(styleName);
    alert( theCSSprop );
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = theCSSprop;
   }
  getTheStyle( "height" ) ;
    getTheStyle( "ime-mode" ) ;
```

you can't read the property which is invalid [because](https://stackoverflow.com/a/250140/1984039)

> Javascript only has access to the DOM, not the code. So no, there is
>   no way to access a property from javascript that the browser itself
>   does not support.

Comment: ok, thanks. So do you have any suggestions to get the invalid property?

Comment: @jack, nope, I don't think it is possible to get the property which browser has deemed invalid and has refused to load it to DOM. If you can't load it to DOM, JS doesn't have access to it.