# How to set non-standard css properties using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to change css using jQuery but `mso-hide` property doesn't get saved using jQuery.

What other solution will be to do this using jQuery?

```
styleCSS = {
    'display': 'none',
    'height' : '0px',
    'line-height' : '0px',
    'max-height' : '0px',
    'overflow' : 'hidden',
    'font-size': '0px',
    'mso-hide' : 'all',
    'width' : '0px',
    'max-width' : '0px'
}
$('.container').find('.hide-me').css(styleCSS);
```

Comment: Have you tried directly implementing the style without using find?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I fetch the value of a non-standard CSS property via Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249991/can-i-fetch-the-value-of-a-non-standard-css-property-via-javascript)

Comment: yes. the same happens

Comment: @AlexandruRada as you can se in my answer live snippet working properly

Comment: You can read https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css/  to customize CSS for MS Outlook

Comment: use a class like normal people do place your css in a css file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set whole style attribute manually

```
var style_text = '';
$.each(styleCSS, function(k,v) {style_text += k+':'+v+';';});
$('.container').find('.hide-me').attr('style', style_text);
```

```js
styleCSS = {
    'display': 'none',
    'height' : '0px',
    'line-height' : '0px',
    'max-height' : '0px',
    'overflow' : 'hidden',
    'font-size': '0px',
    'mso-hide' : 'all',
    'width' : '0px',
    'max-width' : '0px'
};

var style_text = '';
$.each(styleCSS, function(k,v) {style_text += k+':'+v+';';});
$('.container').find('.hide-me').attr('style', style_text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="hide-me">foo</div>
  <div>bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: used a variation of this. Didn't think about using style.

Answer (score 0):

> What other solution will be to do this using jQuery?

An alternative approach would be to declare `var styleCSS` as a string variable (instead of an object) and then simply append an additional `<style>` element to the `<head>` of the document via jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var styleCSS = '.hide-me {display: none; height: 0; line-height: 0; max-height: 0; overflow: hidden; font-size: 0; mso-hide: all; width: 0; max-width: 0;}';

$('head').append('<style>' + styleCSS + '</style>');

});
```